# How to connect a windows desktop and get a file from it using Java

Tags: java

I have a file (file1.txt) in one of the systems (system1) in my network. I would like to connect to this system (system1) from another system (system2) in the same network/other network (i.e. in web) by using it's IP, username and password, and I want to get that file into system2. How can I do this?

```
File f=new File("D:/file1.txt");
if(f.exists())
{
    f.delete();
}
f.createNewFile();
FileObject destn=VFS.getManager().resolveFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
UserAuthenticator auth=new StaticUserAuthenticator("", "username", "password");
FileSystemOptions opts=new FileSystemOptions();
DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
FileObject fo=VFS.getManager().resolveFile("\\\\192.168.1.255\\E$\\Work\\file1.txt",opts);
destn.copyFrom(fo,Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
destn.close();
```

I have got this code from internet but doesn't work for my requirement.
For this I am using below two jars.

1. commons-logging-1.2.jar
2. commons-vfs-2.0.jar

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What does it do? Any Errors?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It says the file doesn't exist in the path. I have worked around and found that the folder I am accessing from machine should be sharable. Can I have any suggestions that I should access a non-sharable folder in the remote machine from my local machine.  @André Stannek

Comment: Could you please check the above comment. @cricket_007

Comment: Yeah, it is working fine with the above broadcast address, admin user and password. Thanks for the help @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what fixed the problem, but apparently this information helps.

Nothing  can be shared at 192.168.1.255 since it is a reserved IP address for the broadcast address. That should be changed to the IP address of the machine that is sharing the folder.

Also, since an admin share (E$) is being accessed, it doesn't matter if the folder is shared as long as an administrator username and password is used.

I also suggest a normal file browser is used to verify a connection can be made before using code

Comment: Yeah, I have changed it. The IP I am using is 192.168.24.255. :)